# Responsive bootstrap carousel possible?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to make a frontpage that has a header, a bootstrap carousel, and a footer. So far it looks like this:

[image]

Apart from some positioning issues, it looks fine. The problem arises when I decide to make it responsive.

By responsive, I mean that the size of the carousel adjusts according to the size of the browser. As it is now, the height is set to a fixed value, `500px`.

If I decide to change the height to `100%`, the entire carousel disappears. I have tried to find a way to use grid to solve my problem, but I couldn't find a way to have a grid that fills the entire frontpage.

So far, this is a small snippet of the css from the carousel:

```
.carousel {
    --main-height: 500px;
    height: var(--main-height);
    grid-area: carousel;
}
```

Here's a snippet of the php page itself:

```
<header id="navbar">
    <nav>
        <?php include "../includes/header.php"?>
    </nav>
</header>

<?php include "../includes/carousel.php"?>

<main>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
</main>

<footer>
    <?php include "../includes/footer.php"?>
</footer>
```

And here's the bit of main css that establishes the grid:

```
body{
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(70,0,0,1),rgba(10,0,0,1)) no-repeat center center fixed;
    display:grid;
    grid-template-rows: 60px auto 150px;
    grid-template-columns: minmax(200px, 1fr) 12fr;
    grid-template-areas: "header header"
                         "main main "
                         "footer footer";
    grid-gap: 50px;
}

#frontpagebody{
    grid-template-rows: 60px auto auto 150px;
    grid-template-areas: "header header"
                         "carousel carousel"
                         "main main"
                         "footer footer";
    grid-gap: 0;
}
```

Things to note: I did try removing the entire `main` in `php` along with the mentions of `main` in the id specific body tag in the main css, which made the footer touch the carousel, but that still didn't help in the end.

Is there a way to set the carousel height, so that it fills the gap between the header and the footer, whichever size the browser has? Or is that just not possible?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was setting everything into terms of `vh`.

`1vh` = `1%` of browser height. So what I had to do was this.

1. Fix the position of header and footer.
2. Take note of the height of header and footer.
3. Set the height of the carousel to `100vh - (header height + footer
   height)`.

Since the only three elements on the page are the header, footer and carousel, that last calculation meant that the entire page was filled, as the whole `100vh` was used up. No matter how much I resized the browser, it fit in well.